# c# gridview multiple filter

Tags: c#, winforms

Can I make multiple filter in gridview? So far I have three separate methods for each kind of filtering. I want to be able to do something like this. First choose from combobox value which will be shown and then from this filtered list, I would like to be able to search by using textbox for something else.

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = list3.Where(Srodek => Srodek.Srodek.ID.Device == textBox2.Text).ToList();
    dataGridView4.DataSource = result;
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = list3.Where(Srodek => Srodek.Srodek.category1 == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()).ToList();
    dataGridView4.DataSource = result;
}
```

Now when I choose some value from combobox it show what I want in gridview, but later when I insert something in textbox and click the button, it is filtering the whole list not this one already filtered by combobox. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Make one method FilteredResult thats bind to the datagrid. In this method you can look at multiple filters

Comment: What is the type of the element in `list3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `FilterDataGrid()` calling on both events:

```
    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FilterDataGrid();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FilterDataGrid();
    }

    private void FilterDataGrid()
    {
        var _text = Convert.ToString(textBox2.Text);
        var _comboText = ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text) ? Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedItem) : string.Empty;
        var result = list3.Where(Srodek => Srodek.Srodek.category1 == _comboText || Srodek.Srodek.ID.Device == _text).ToList();
        //
        dataGridView4.DataSource = result;
    }
```

Hopes this helps u.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the type of element in `list3` is `T`:

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dataGridView4.DataSource is IEnumerable<T>){
      var result = ((IEnumerable<T>)dataGridView4.DataSource).Where(Srodek => Srodek.Srodek.ID.Device == textBox2.Text).ToList();
      dataGridView4.DataSource = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a global property that will host your list so that everytime you perform a query on the list you perform a query on your up to date list that has already been filtered.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't changing the source of you filter, so you are filtering on the same set each time. One option would be to have the original dataset and a filtered dataset, then when you filter the original save the results in the filtered set.